# Python - __init__() missing 1 required positional argument:

Tags: python

I'm kinda new to python and I can't get past this error:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "***", line 63, in <module>
    bst = Node()
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'val'
```

Basically, the program is a BST which would allow you to insert, search and look for the minimum item by only going left.

Here's the code (sorry, it's hungarian)

```
class Node:
        def __init__(self, val):
                self.ertek = val
                self.balgyerek = None 
                self.jobbgyerek = None
                self.gyoker = None

        def beszur(self, pri):
                if self.gyoker: 
                        return self.gyoker.beszur(pri)
                else: 
                        self.gyoker = Node(pri)
                        return True
                if self.ertek == pri: 
                        return False
                elif self.ertek > pri: 
                        if self.balgyerek: 
                                return self.balgyerek.beszur(pri) 
                        else:
                                self.balgyerek = Node(pri) 
                                return True
                else: 
                        if self.jobbgyerek:
                                return self.jobbgyerek.beszur(pri)
                        else:
                                self.jobbgyerek = Node(pri)
                                return True
        def keres(self, pri):
                if self.gyoker: 
                        return self.gyoker.keres(pri) 
                else: 
                        return False 

                if(self.ertek == pri): 
                        return True
                elif self.ertek > pri: 
                        if self.balgyerek:
                                return self.balgyerek.keres(pri) 
                        else:
                                return False 
                else:
                        if self.jobbgyerek:
                                return self.jobbgyerek.keres(pri)
                        else:
                                return False
        def minimumertek(self): 
                jelenlegi = self

                while(jelenlegi.balgyerek is not None):
                        jelenlegi = jelenlegi.balgyerek

                return self.ertek 

bst = Node()
```

Comment: A `Node` requires a `val`. You don't provide one.

Comment: Your class has `val` property , but when you create a `Node` object didn't pass any value to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `__init__` method is run as soon as an object of a class is instantiated. Your `__init__` method has two positional arguments: **self** which refers to the object instance and is passed automatically, and **val** which is assigned to **self.ertek**. However, you didn't pass the value of **val**. Hence, the error. Try passing the value of **val** at the class instantiation. e.g **bst = Node('ertek value')**